# If jquery DropDown selected value is "y/n" update textfield

Tags: jquery-selectors, if-statement

I want to update a text box when a drop down is either select to Yes or No.  The code I have checks it the is an option for Y or N. How to I check  which value is selected?

html

```
<select id="SelectionFlag" name="SelectionFlag">
<option value="">Select one</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Y">Yes</option>
<option value="N">No</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
 $("#SelectionFlag").change(function () {
                var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
                alert(currentYear + 1);
                if ($("#SelectionFlag").value = "N") {

                    $("#TermDate").val("12/31/" + currentYear);
                }
                if($("#SelectionFlag").value = "Y")
                {
                    $("#EffectiveDate").val("12/31/" + (currentYear + 1));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your IF statements to:

```
if ($("#SelectionFlag").val() == "N")
```

and

```
if ($("#SelectionFlag").val() == "Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#SelectionFlag").change(function() {
    var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
    // alert(currentYear + 1);
    if ($(this).val() == "N") {
        $("#TermDate").val("12/31/" + currentYear);
    } else if ($(this).val() == "Y") {
        $("#EffectiveDate").val("12/31/" + (currentYear + 1));
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/n4Ggz/

Answer (score 0):

replace `$("#SelectionFlag").value` with `$("#SelectionFlag").val()`